# Very weird behavior: Class with template constructor with only one argument

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

Recently I've bumped into a weird behavior when having a class with a template constructor that accepts only one argument. This class under certain circumstances fails to initialize at all.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    template<typename T>
    Foo(const T& x)
    {
        std::cout << "--" << x << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    Foo f(std::string());

    std::cout << "++" << f << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What I have is a Foo structure with the constructor you see. In main I create a new Foo instance with an empty std::string. The example compiles and the output is:

```
++1
```

WTF??? As you may have noticed there are **three problems** with the this. First of all the constructor was never called, secondly the f was printed as "1", thirdly there is no overloaded operator<< that prints the Foo using the cout and despite that the compiler never complained. This means that the f is not a type of Foo.

I change the example slightly:

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    Foo f(std::string(""));

    std::cout << "++" << f << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

...and the compiler throws an error that there is no overloaded operator<< and that is normal.

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    Foo f(std::string("Hello"));
    return 0;
}
```

Now the output is:

```
--Hello
```

and that's normal again.

The problem is when having passing to Foo::Foo a an empty object whether it is std::string() or float() or any_type(). I've tested the example in GCC 4.4 and 4.6 and I find this behavior very unexpected.

What is your opinion? Is this a GCC bug or am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm guessing it is interpreting `f` as a function pointer, I'm not clear as to why. For example, this also corrects it `Foo f = Foo(std::string);`

Comment: Copy and paste your example and it does not link in visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 5):

```
Foo f(std::string());
```

It does not create an instance of type `Foo`, as you seem to think.

Instead, this declares a function of name `f`, whose return type is `Foo`, and parameter type is a function type (which takes no argument and returns `std::string`).

It is same as:

```
Foo f(std::string (*)()); //same as yours
```

The only difference this and your function declaration is that in your case the parameter type is *function type* (which eventually decays into *function **pointer** type* anyway), and in my case, the parameter type is *function **pointer** type* (which doesn't need to decay into *pointer* type).

As for why it prints `++1` is because it invokes `operator<<` which takes `void*`  as argument, and this function prints the address of the function.

Now if you want to declare an object, then you need to use extra parens as:

```
Foo f((std::string())); //notice the extra parens!
```

This declares an object, and calls the constructor : http://ideone.com/Px815

---

See also this topic:

- [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

Comment: Link to ideone seems to be broken. For me only?

Answer (score 2):

You're experiencing the infamous C++ [Most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). In your first example

```
 Foo f(std::string());
```

is parsed as a function declaration, so no constructor is called.